# How to modify document in collection in discovery service

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

How can I modify or delete document in my collection in IBM Watson Discovery service ?

Comment: apparently you can delete using this api https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/curl.html?curl

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a document by calling the [delete document API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/curl.html?curl#delete-document).

You can update a document by calling the [update document API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/curl.html?curl#update-document).